# TypeError: schedule_translation() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I'm new to python and therefore I can't figure out what the problem is. When I try to call the function:
def schedule_translation(event),
an error appears in the function:
def ex_button().
TypeError: schedule_translation() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'

```
from languages import lang, lang_to_translate
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from googletrans import Translator
import pyperclip as clipboard

after_id = None
language_abbreviation = []

def copy_text():
    text = text2.get('1.0', END).strip()
    clipboard.copy(text)

def clear_text():
    text1.delete('1.0', END)

def defocus(event):
    event.widget.master.focus_set()

def get_choice1(event):
    global choice_language1
    choice_language1 = language_selection1.get()

def get_choice2(event):
    global choice_language2
    choice_language2 = language_selection2.get()

def ex_button():
    c1 = language_selection1.get()
    c2 = language_selection2.get()
    label1.configure(text=c1)
    label2.configure(text=c2)
    language_selection1.set(c2)
    language_selection2.set(c1)
    get_choice1('event')
    get_choice2('event')

    text = text2.get('1.0', END).strip()
    text2.delete('1.0', END)
    text1.delete('1.0', END)
    text1.insert(1.0, text)

    schedule_translation()


def do_translation():
    pass
    # global language_abbreviation
    # global choice_language1
    # global choice_language2
    # dest = lang.index(choice_language2)
    # language_abbreviation = lang_to_translate[dest]

    #text = text1.get('1.0', END).strip()

    # translator = Translator()
    # translated_text = translator.translate(text, dest=language_abbreviation)
    #
    # text2.delete('1.0', END)
    # text2.insert(END, translated_text.text)

def schedule_translation(event):
    global after_id
    if after_id is not None:
        event.widget.after_cancel(after_id)
    after_id = event.widget.after(500, do_translation)


root = Tk()

app_width = 800
app_height = 500
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
x = (screen_width / 2) - (app_width / 2)
y = (screen_height / 2) - (app_height / 2)

root.title('Переводчик')
root['bg'] = '#1D1B26'
root.geometry(f'{app_width}x{app_height}+{int(x)}+{int(y)}')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

language_selection1 = ttk.Combobox(root, values=lang, font='Comfortaa 10')
language_selection1.current(1)
language_selection1.place(relx=0.16,y=50)
language_selection1.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', get_choice1)
language_selection1.bind('<FocusIn>', defocus)

label1 = Label(root)

exchange_button = PhotoImage(file='transfer.png')
img_label = Label(image=exchange_button)
exchange_button = exchange_button.subsample(18,18)
exchange_button1 = Button(root, image=exchange_button,
                          bg='#2ee59d',highlightthickness=0,
                          bd=0, command=ex_button)
exchange_button1.place(relx=0.49, y=50)

language_selection2 = ttk.Combobox(root, values=lang, font='Comfortaa 10')
language_selection2.set('Выберите язык')
language_selection2.place(relx=0.66, y=50)
language_selection2.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', get_choice2)
language_selection2.bind('<FocusIn>', defocus)

first_frame = Frame(root, bg='Black')
first_frame.place(x=41, y=100, width= 250, height=200) #127

text1 = Text(first_frame, bg='#FFC0CB')
text1.bind('<Any-KeyRelease>', schedule_translation)
text1.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

clear_button = PhotoImage(file='clear_button.png')
clear_button_label = Label(image=clear_button)
clear_button = clear_button.subsample(25, 25)
clear_button1 = Button(text1, image=clear_button,
                       highlightthickness = 0, bd = 0,bg='#FFC0CB',
                       activebackground='#FFC0CB', command=clear_text)
clear_button1.pack(side='top', anchor='e', pady=5, padx=5)

label2 = Label(root)

second_frame = Frame(root, bg='Black')
second_frame.place(x=528, y=100, width= 250, height=200) #441

text2 = Text(second_frame, bg='#FFC0CB')
text2.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

copying_text = PhotoImage(file='copying_text.png')
copying_text_label = Label(image=copying_text)
copying_text = copying_text.subsample(18, 18)
copying_text1 = Button(text2, image=copying_text,
                       highlightthickness = 0, bd = 0, bg='#FFC0CB',
                       activebackground='#FFC0CB', command=copy_text)
copying_text1.pack(side='top', anchor='e')

root.mainloop()
```

P.S: I commented out the def do_translation() function: because Google issues a ban for frequent requests.

Comment: Your function was designed to be called in response to an event. You'll need to redesign it if you want to be able to directly call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the current design of `schedule_translation()`, it can be re-designed to not depending on the passed `event` argument and make it having default value as below:

```py
# set default value to argument event
def schedule_translation(event=None):
    global after_id
    # use root.after() instead of event.widget.after()
    if after_id is not None:
        root.after_cancel(after_id)
    after_id = root.after(500, do_translation)
```

Then the function can be called with (via binding) or without (via direct call) the event argument.